# impersonating on remote machine

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wmi, remote-access, impersonation

i want to impersonate user while i am connected on remote machine. i able to connect remote machine even able to start a process. but after that when i check for activeconsolesession it returns me my localmachines active session, not of remote computers.(m already connected to remote machine). here is my code

```
  public void impersonateSystem()
    {
        IntPtr tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;

        ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();
        conn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        conn.EnablePrivileges = true;
        string remote="window-PC";
        conn.Username = "administrator";
        conn.Password = "pass";
        conn.EnablePrivileges = true;
        ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2",remote ), conn);
        manScope.Connect();

           conn.EnablePrivileges = true;
        ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
        ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
        ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inParams["CommandLine"] = "cmd.exe  'C:\\v.exe'" ;
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
        Console.WriteLine("Creation of the process returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Process ID: " + outParams["processId"]);


               PROCESS_INFORMATION pi1;

               var si1 = new STARTUPINFO();
               var sa1 = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
               si1.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
               si1.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";
               uint dwCreationFlags1 = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
               IntPtr pEnv1 = IntPtr.Zero;


               uint dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(); 
               WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, ref hUserToken);

               WindowsIdentity who1 = new WindowsIdentity(hUserToken);
               who1.Impersonate();

              bool  bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserToken,"C:\\pr.exe",null, ref sa1,ref sa1,false,(int)dwCreationFlags1,pEnv1,null,ref si1, out pi1);
                Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                CloseHandle(hUserToken); 
                CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
                impersonationEnabled = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

why WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(); is returning me local active console session not remote activeconsole session.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx *The session identifier returned by this function **is the identifier of the current physical console session***.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes. but when i am connected to  remote session . i was expecting current physical console session of remote machine. any idea how to get that.

Comment: You may have to run that command remotely, I can't see an API for returning the remote machine console session id, but to be honest I didn't spend a lot of time digging through the MSDN.